# Push build.prop to /system/build.prop

Tags: android, build, adb

I have edited build.prop and now my phone cannot boot. I have pulled build.prop using adb and now I have the correct build.prop file

**What I need is to push build.prop using adb.**

First try: ***Read-only file system***

[image]

when I mount system:

Second try: ***Permision Denied***

[image]

what can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried the following code... it works but i do not know if is the solution because my phone still cannot boot.

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/stl9 /system
chmod 777 /system
exit
exit

adb push build.prop /system
```

please let me know if the following code is correct or not...

Comment: Hi, when I wrote su , this return "/system/bin/sh: su: not found
"

Answer (score 7):

Probably because `adb push` uses the `shell` user, which does not have write permissions to `/system/build.prop`. You can, however, push the file to a different location first (e.g. `/data/local/tmp/`) and then move the file to the right place with the root user (after mounting).

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I tried changing permissions on /system and build.prop itself, remounting /system any number of ways, but I just couldn't get it to push directly.

Answer (score 7):

Here are the commands you need to use:

```
adb push <Path to build.prop>/build.prop /data/local/tmp/
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
adb push /data/local/tmp/build.prop /system/build.prop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
adb remount
adb push build.prop /system/
adb shell chmod 644 /system/build.prop
adb reboot
```

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS UNLESS YOU WANT TO REINSTALL YOUR ANDROID IMAGE

Answer (score 2):

this works for me for Galaxy S6:

cd C:\Users[here the userprofilename]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>

1.) adb pull /system/build.prop

```
- this download the file from the phone in the adb folder
- edit the file, then load up to the phone:
```

2.) adb root

3.) adb root remount rw

4.) adb root chmod 664 /system/build.prop

5.) adb root push ./build.prop /system/build.prop

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell
 su
 mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/st19 /system
 chmod 777 /system
 exit 
exit
push build.prop /system
adb shell
 su
 chmod 644 /system/build.prop
 exit
exit
reboot
```

that worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. adb push \build.prop /data/local/tmp/
2. adb shell
3. su
4. rm /system/build.prop
5. cp /data/local/tmp/build.prop /system
6. exit
7. exit
8. adb reboot

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Ok lets do it. i found a simple way to by pass root permissions.

If u have a CWM recovery... enter on it and on "mounts and storage" enter and mounts /system/ them your pc will recognize it on adb push and send it to system. 
Use your command codes above you write them voilá... your tablet/phone will boot again. if you have a backup of original build.prop